# Assign value to array indexes through loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am struggling to find apply the loop function to an array and I was hoping you could help me. I have a group list and I want to automatically assign people requests to groups and assign these to areas where there are vacancies.
Therefore im looking at a table where I would get :
Group 1 | NB People
Group 2 | NB People
Group 3 | NB People
and so on...

I therefore know I need an "if" condition to check compare people request with vacancies in each group and then assign it if vacancy in group is higher than reservation request. 
I know how to add the reservation variable to an array with the array.push function but I am struggling to loop and assign to an array containing 2 columns...

```
    <label for="groups">Reservation request (1-10):</label>
    <div id="reservation">
    <input type="number" name="form" id="number" min="1" max='10'>
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="groups()">Submit</button>
    </div>



 var myArray = ["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3"];
 function groups(){
 form = number.value;
 if (form >=1){  
     for (var i; i<myArray.length; i++) {
         if (myArray[i] > form){
             myArray[i] = form;
             console.log(myArray);
         }
         else {alert("no");}
```

Can you help me out please?

Many thanks
Marion

Comment: thanks @NickParsons - Ive edited this!

Comment: What is `number`? Your unclear use of terminology makes it really hard to guess what you want to achieve.

Comment: @connexo   you're right, added the html part too

Comment: Could you please add a more complete code sample, as we still do not know enough, e.g. about your `myArray`, to be able to help you or to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Try to create a runnable snippet. Use the `<>`button for that.

Comment: @Beppo - Ive added it! I hesitated in between setting an empty array and storing value with the loop -> example each group can take 10 persons so if group is full, it adds people to the next one. If they are all full, it creates a new group. Or setting a fix group of table from the start.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, what you want to do is:

- start with a list of some empty groups, who can grow when adding people, but never grow above 10 members
- on request (button press) add an arbitrary number of people to the first group that can take all requested members
- if no group can take all requested members, add a new group and add the request to that.

Assuming this, the easiset way is not to use multi-dimensional arrays ("arrays with two columns):

```
var myArray = [0,0,0];

function groups() {
    var form = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (form >=1) {  
        for (var i; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i] < 10 - form) {
                myArray[i] += form;
                return;
            }
        }
        myArray.push(form); // this will only happen if "return" up there never happened
    }
    else {alert("no");
}
```

If you want that group-name / a multi-dimensional array, you can do it like this:

```
var myArray = [['Group 0',0], ['Group 1',0], ['Group 2',0]];

function groups() {
    var form = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (form >=1) {  
        for (var i; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i][1] < 10 - form) { // myArray[i][1] is the number of reservations in group i, myArray[i][0] would be the group's name
                myArray[i][1] += form;
                return;
            }
        }
        myArray.push(['Group ' + myArray.length, form); // this will only happen if "return" up there never happened
    }
    else {alert("no");
}
```

For better readability, you can use structured objects inside myArray instead of more arrays:

```
var myArray = [{name:'Group 0',reserved:0}, {name:'Group 1',reserved:0}, {name:'Group 2',reserved:0}];

function groups() {
    var form = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (form >=1) {  
        for (var i; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].reserved < 10 - form) { // myArray[i].reserved is the number of reservations in group i, myArray[i].name would be the group's name
                myArray[i].reserved += form;
                return;
            }
        }
        myArray.push({name:'Group ' + myArray.length, reserved:form); // this will only happen if "return" up there never happened
    }
    else {alert("no");
}
```